# How to find Date Time Range in Python

Tags: python, date, range

time range like this

```
strart_date_time = datetime(2021, 1, 1, 5, 00, 00)
end_date_time = datetime(2021,1, 3, 00,00,00)
```

I want Output Like This I mean I want every single second count between given time range hope you understand.....
ThankYou in advance

```
output-
2021, 1, 1, 0, 00, 01
2021, 1, 1, 0, 01, 02
2021, 1, 1, 2, 30, 03
...
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Daweo I don't know how to solve ... Please help me but i tried this

Comment: sdate = datetime(2021, 1, 1, 5, 00, 00)   # start date
edate = datetime(2021,1, 3, 00,00,00)   # end date
delta = edate - sdate       # as timedelta
for i in range(delta.seconds + 1):
    day = sdate + timedelta(seconds=i)
    print(day)

Comment: add the code to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the time difference in seconds, loop and display new date at each second

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start_date_time = datetime(2021, 1, 1, 5, 00, 00)
end_date_time = datetime(2021,1, 3, 00,00,00)
time_diff = int((end_date_time - start_date_time).total_seconds())

for i in range(time_diff):
    print(start_date_time + timedelta(0, i))
```

Comment: can i get new date at each Minute also ???

Comment: changing the code to int((end_date_time - start_date_time).total_seconds() / 60) and timedelta(minutes=i) should do it

Comment: thankyou sir I'm absolute beginners and I'm practicing my self...